# Why does the best score from gridsearch and score from the model with the best parameters differ?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, train-test-split, mse

I am using Grid search with predefined split. I want to choose the best hyperparameters for my model based on MSE score on validation dataset. Here is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data/concrete.csv').astype(float)
X = data.drop('concrete_compressive_strength', axis=1)
y = data.concrete_compressive_strength
n = len(X)

X_train_val, X_test, y_train_val, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=int(n*0.15), random_state=0xC0FFEE)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train_val, y_train_val, 
                                                  test_size=int(n*0.15), random_state=0xC0FFEE)
### BEGIN Solution (do not delete this comment)
validation_indexies = [0 if index in X_val.index else -1 for index in X_train_val.index]
validation_split = PredefinedSplit(validation_indexies)
score = make_scorer(mse)
rf_params = {'n_estimators' : np.linspace(100, 1000, num = 10).astype(int),
             'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt'],
             'max_depth': np.linspace(10, 100, num = 10).astype(int)}

rf_regressor = GridSearchCV(estimator = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 2022, n_jobs = -1), 
                          cv = validation_split, 
                          param_grid = rf_params, 
                          scoring = score, 
                          n_jobs = -1)

rf_regressor.fit(X_train_val, y_train_val) # use these datasets because work with predefined split
#refit the model manually because in gridsearch refit method X_train_val will be used, but I need to train model 
#on X_train dataset
random_forest = RandomForestRegressor(**rf_regressor.best_params_, random_state = 2022, n_jobs = -1)
random_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(f'Random forest best parameters: {rf_regressor.best_params_}')
print(f'Random forest MSE on validation: {mse(random_forest.predict(X_val), y_val)}')
print(f'Random forest MSE on train: {mse(random_forest.predict(X_train), y_train)}')
print(f'Random forest MSE on test: {mse(random_forest.predict(X_test), y_test)}')
print(f'Grid search best score {rf_regressor.best_score_}')
### END Solution (do not delete this comment)
```

Here is an output:

```
    Random forest best parameters: {'max_depth': 10, 'max_features': 'sqrt', 'n_estimators': 700}
Random forest MSE on validation: 23.70519021501106
Random forest MSE on train: 9.496448922692428
Random forest MSE on test: 29.05420154977391
Grid search best score 24.03263333882673
```

My question is why does the MSE for random forest with the best parameters (MSE for validation dataset on which I tuned hyperparameters through gridsearch) differ from the gridsearch.best_params_?

Comment: Check `rf_regressor.cv_results_`? It may have something to do with the ordering of the samples when training being inconsistent. (Not related to the issue, but note that the grid search tries to _maximize_ its score, so you're getting the _worst_ parameters rather than the best. Use `scoring='neg_mean_squared_error'`  in the search, or `greater_is_better=False` in `make_scorer`.)

Answer (score 1):

Best score is the "Mean cross-validated score of the best_estimator" for your best hyperparameter search. RandomisedGridsearchCV tunes the hyperparameters and selects the model having the highest score. Selection is based on the score for left-out fold, not the training score. The best estimator has the highest score for the left-out fold meaning that the difference between the scores for the unseen and training datasets for this model is less than the rest of trained models. In other words, this method selects the model with the lowest degree of overfitting.

On the other hand, score from the model is the proportion of variance of your dependent variable (y) explained by the independent variable (x). Thus, the closer it is to 1, the better your regression line fits the data and the better your model is.